# CouchDB error in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Seeing the following error

CouchDB error:
2017-05-30 14:24:07.695 EDT [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 2c45 HTTP Request: GET /chain_0008/testChaincode%00key_000000222?attachments=true HTTP/1.1 | Host: 127.0.0.1:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |

2017-05-30 14:24:07.695 EDT [couchdb] ReadDoc -> DEBU 2c41 couchDBReturn=
panic: Error:Get http://127.0.0.1:5984/chain_0006/testChaincode%00key_000000269?attachments=true: EOF

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with concurrency and not enough resources available. You will need to increase the maximum number of open files descriptors. This can be done with :

First verify you have enough system resource allocated to the shell:

```
ulimit -a
```

When running at a high volume you probably would want something like 40000. To increase the ulimit use the following command:

```
ulimit -n 40000
```

Now for the CouchDB specific settings. CouchDB uses Least Recently Used (LRU) cache to manage open databases, and closes databases as needed. The current default setting is 8000, which should handle a fairly significant currency load. Deployments with large numbers of channels and high concurrency may need to increase this setting. Specify the number of database shards that can be open concurrently. Beware too high of a setting can impact your local resources since this is utilizing more memory resources.

To increase the maximum number of open shards in CouchDB edit fabric/images/couchdb/local.ini change

```
max_open_dbs=8000
```

This default setting is set so each database(channel) will have 8 shards. Meaning, for concurrency of 1000 channels the minimum setting of max_dbs_open would be 8000 (our current default). max_dbs_open=number of channels * shards per database.

After these setting changes you will then build your image.